# Print to standard output from a function defined in an Fortran module

Tags: fortran

I'm trying to learn Fortran (unfortunately a necessity for my research group) - one of the tasks I set myself was to package one of the necessary functions (Associated Legendre polynomials) from the Numerical Recipes book into a fortran 03 compliant module. The original program (f77) has some error handling in the form of the following:

```
if(m.lt.0.or.m.gt.1.or.abs(x).gt.1)pause 'bad arguments in plgndr'
```

Pause seems to have been deprecated since f77 as using this line gives me a compiling error, so I tried the following:

```
module sha_helper
    implicit none
    public :: plgndr, factorial!, ylm

contains
    ! numerical recipes Associated Legendre Polynomials rewritten for f03
    function plgndr(l,m,x) result(res_plgndr)
        integer, intent(in) :: l, m
        real, intent(in) :: x
        real :: res_plgndr, fact, pll, pmm, pmmp1, somx2
        integer ::  i,ll
        if (m.lt.0.or.m.gt.l.or.abs(x).gt.1) then 
            write (*, *) "bad arguments to plgndr, aborting", m, x
            res_plgndr=-10e6 !return a ridiculous value
        else
            pmm = 1.
            if (m.gt.0) then
                somx2 = sqrt((1.-x)*(1.+x))
                fact = 1.
                do i = 1, m
                    pmm = -pmm*fact*somx2
                    fact = fact+2
                end do
            end if
            if (l.eq.m) then
                res_plgndr = pmm
            else
                pmmp1 = x*(2*m+1)*pmm
                if(l.eq.m+1) then
                    res_plgndr = pmmp1
                else
                    do ll = m+2, l
                        pll = (x*(2*ll-1)*pmmp1-(ll+m-1)*pmm)/(ll-m)
                        pmm = pmmp1
                        pmmp1 = pll
                    end do
                    res_plgndr = pll
                end if
            end if
        end if
    end function plgndr

    recursive function factorial(n) result(factorial_result)
        integer, intent(in) :: n
        integer, parameter :: RegInt_K = selected_int_kind(20) !should be enough for the factorials I am using
        integer (kind = RegInt_K) :: factorial_result
        if (n <= 0) then
            factorial_result = 1
        else 
            factorial_result = n * factorial(n-1)
        end if 
    end function factorial

!     function ylm(l,m,theta,phi) result(res_ylm)
!         integer, intent(in) :: l, m
!         real, intent(in) :: theta, phi
!         real :: res_ylm, front_block
!         real, parameter :: pi = 3.1415926536
!         front_block = sqrt((2*l+1)*factorial(l-abs(m))/(4*pi*))
!     end function ylm

end module sha_helper
```

The main code after the else works, but if I execute my main program and call the function with bad values, the program freezes before executing the print statement. I know that the print statement is the problem, as commenting it out allows the function to execute normally, returning -10e6 as the value. Ideally, I would like the program to crash after giving a user readable error message, as giving bad values to the plgndr function is a fatal error for the program. The function plgndr is being used by the program sha_lmc. Currently all this does is read some arrays and then print a value of plgndr for testing (early days). The function ylm in the module sha_helper is also not finished, hence it is commented out. The code compiles using gfortran sha_helper.f03 sha_lmc.f03 -o sha_lmc, and
gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (GCC) 4.8.2

```
!Spherical Harmonic Bayesian Analysis testbed for Lagrangian Dynamical Monte Carlo

program sha_analysis
use sha_helper
implicit none
!Analysis Parameters
integer, parameter :: harm_order = 6
integer, parameter :: harm_array_length = (harm_order+1)**2
real, parameter :: coeff_lo = -0.1, coeff_hi = 0.1, data_err = 0.01 !for now, data_err fixed rather than heirarchical
!Monte Carlo Parameters
integer, parameter :: run = 100000, burn = 50000, thin = 100
real, parameter :: L = 1.0, e = 1.0

!Variables needed by the program
integer :: points, r, h, p, counter = 1
real, dimension(:), allocatable :: x, y, z 
real, dimension(harm_array_length) :: l_index_list, m_index_list
real, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: g_matrix

!Open the file, allocate the x,y,z arrays and read the file
open(1, file = 'Average_H_M_C_PcP_boschi_1200.xyz', status = 'old')
read(1,*) points
allocate(x(points))
allocate(y(points))
allocate(z(points))
print *, "Number of Points: ", points
readloop: do r = 1, points
    read(1,*) x(r), y(r), z(r)
end do readloop

!Set up the forwards model
allocate(g_matrix(harm_array_length,points))
!Generate the l and m values of spherical harmonics
hloop: do h = 0, harm_order
    ploop: do p = -h,h
        l_index_list(counter) = h
        m_index_list(counter) = p
        counter = counter + 1
    end do ploop
end do hloop

print *, plgndr(1,2,0.1)
!print *, ylm(1,1,0.1,0.1)


end program sha_analysis
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete code. There are apparently no errors in the included program fragment. So, it might be due to something in other part of your program.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your program does what is known as recursive IO - the initial call to `plgndr` is in the output item list of an IO statement (a print statement) [directing output to the console] - inside that function you then also attempt to execute another IO statement [that outputs to the console].  This is not permitted - see 9.11p2 and p3 of F2003 or 9.12p2 of F2008.

A solution is to separate the function invocation from the io statement in the main program, i.e.

```
REAL :: a_temporary
...
a_temporary = plgndr(1,2,0.1)
PRINT *, a_temporary
```

Other alternatives in F2008 (but not F2003 - hence the [ ] parts in the first paragraph) include directing the output from the function to a different logical unit (note that `WRITE (*, ...` and `PRINT ...` reference the same unit).

In F2008 you could also replace the WRITE statement with a STOP statement with a message (the message must be a constant - which wouldn't let you report the problematic values).

The potential for inadvertently invoking recursive IO is part of the reason that some programming styles discourage conducting IO in functions.

Comment: Thanks --- if one was to avoid IO in the function in this case, is there a good way of placing error checking in the main code? I guess you could pick a return value well outside the range of the function and check for that? That seems like it is fraught with peril though...

Comment: It depends.  First I'd consider whether the function should actually be a subroutine, with a separate error flag argument or similar.  If it still makes sense to be a function (i.e. I expect it to be referenced as a primary in more complicated expressions) then I also prefer my functions to be PURE - this currently rules out using [ERROR] STOP or doing IO (though the restriction on ERROR STOP might be removed in future standards).  If supported a good "invalid" value is to use `IEEE_VALUE(x, IEEE_QUIET_NAN)` as it tends to propagate sensibly when subsequently used.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if (m.lt.0.or.m.gt.l.or.abs(x).gt.1) then
   write (*, *) "bad arguments to plgndr, aborting", m, x
   stop
else
   ...
end if
```